# mysql query joining tables to create newsfeed

Tags: mysql, database, feed

I want to retrieve rows from 3 tables - LikeTable, ClosetTable, FollowTable to display the activities of all the users a person is following. This is for a website. ClosetTable is the table for the user's products. LikeTable is the table for the likes of the products and Followtable for the following and followers.

Currently, I have

```
SELECT c.user, c.productName
FROM ClosetTable AS c
LEFT JOIN FollowTable AS f ON c.user = f.isFollowed
WHERE f.follows = 'tony'
```

This returns the rows of the person, 'tony' is following together with the productname. However, I want rows from the LikeTable and FollowTable in the same manner altogether. So can you suggest a way to do only 1 query to get rows from all 3 tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something that look like this :

```
SELECT c.user, c.productName
FROM FollowTable AS f
INNER JOIN ClosetTable AS c ON c.user = f.isFollowed
INNER JOIN LikeTable AS l ON c.user = l.userliked
WHERE f.follows = 'tony'
```

I do some assumption for fields name since you didn't provide the structures of your tables.

Also, I suggested that you put the FollowTable in the FROM clause and then join it to ClosetTable since you put f.follows = 'tony' in your WHERE clause.

Otherwise, remove the WHERE clause and put the condition in the INNER JOIN.
Something like :

```
LEFT JOIN FollowTable AS f ON c.user = f.isFollowed AND f.follows = 'tony'
```

Comment: Hi thankyou for your prompt response. Your query works almost like I wanted it to just that, however I am unable to distinguish from which table each row is from. The query joins all the selected fields together, regardless of which table it comes from.
For example,`code`
achipa02   9 miazima 
achipa02   9 heavens
`/code`
the 9 (product_liked) appears twice, when achipa02 follows miazima and heavens. it shouldn't be there.

Comment: [achipa02   9 miazima ]\
[achipa02   9 heavens ]

Comment: The row itself contain column from all tables. In my example c.user and c.productName are coming from "ClosetTable AS c" but you can add any other field. The SELECT can look like : 
SELECT f.follows, c.user, c.productName, etc.

Answer (score 0):

More JOINs:

```
SELECT c.user, c.productName
FROM ClosetTable AS c
LEFT JOIN FollowTable AS f ON c.user = f.isFollowed
JOIN LikeTable as l on c.user = l.liked
WHERE f.follows = 'tony'
```

or something like that.  You aren't restricted to one JOIN.